# Counting the number of lines (csv module)

Tags: python

I have a csv file and i want to transform it into a numerical dataset. To do so,i read every lines of the file and apply  a function that keeps what i want and print it in another csv file.

What I also want to do is to count the number of lines that I have read (number of lines in the original dataset)  and the number of errors that have occured (the original dataset has some bugs and my function will raise error)

Problem : With the following code I use (see below) returns  only half of the exact number of lines. Indeed, when I use it on a file with exactly 1 000 000 lines , nb_lines is only 500 000. And as I want to record the lines that are not "good", I guess that I must record the wrong lines:/

```
data=csv.reader(open(path1,"rb"),delimiter=';',skipinitialspace=True)
output=csv.writer(open(path2,"wb"))
error=csv.writer(open(path3,"wb"))
nb_error=0
nb_lines=0
for row in data:
    nb_lines=nbr_lines+1
    try:
        liste=data.next()
        toprint=function(liste)
        output.writerow(aprinter)
    except Exception as e:
        nb_error=nb_error+1
        badline=[nb_lines,e]
        error.writerow(badline)
```

What is wrong with my loop?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `nb_lines=nbr_lines+1` do you have the typo in the code you run?

Comment: Sorry, I did not properly paste my code. I changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increment your iterator within the loop, for some reason. `for row in data` makes `row` the next line through each time. But then you do `liste=data.next()` - so you increment again. That means you skip every other line: it's not just your counter that is wrong, but you actually miss out half the data.

You should delete that line, and refer to `row` rather than `liste` within the loop.

Comment: Wow , big mistake indeed. Thanks much for pointing this out ! You saved my life ^^

Answer (score 0):

You skip a row each time you execute this `liste = data.next()`. I also changed the increment, in python is it shortened to  `+=`.

```
data = csv.reader(open(path1,"rb"),delimiter=';',skipinitialspace=True)
output = csv.writer(open(path2,"wb"))
error = csv.writer(open(path3,"wb"))
nb_error = 0
nb_lines = 0
for row in data:
    nb_lines +=1
    try:
        toprint = function(row)
        output.writerow(aprinter)
    except Exception as e:
        nb_error += 1
        badline = [nb_lines,e]
        errors.writerow(badline)
```

You could also store the line changing `nb_lines` to `row`, so probably it would be easier to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered, but you could simplify your code by using:

> [csvreader.line_num](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.line_num) - The number of lines read from the source iterator.
>   This is not the same as the number of records returned, as records can
>   span multiple lines.

In the future if you need to iterate and count, you should consider using python's [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function.  Here's sample code from the documentation:

```
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
>>> list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
[(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
```

Less code == Less Bugs, well generally speaking :D